# javascript function call in html href not working properly with the mouse wheel click in FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to call a javaScript function inside `href` attribute in html `< a >` tag.

In Chrome it's working fine. but in Firefox there is a problem.

It is not properly calling the function when we click the mouse wheel. Instead it will open a new browser tab with the `href` content.

[use this fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/5EJuu/)  to view it. open it in firefox. It wont trigger the function when mouse wheel click.

How can I overcome that and make it work.

NOTE : The href url should be generated in that function which called by it.

Comment: I don't know the exact cause of the issue, but it would be much better to attach an event handler to the element through JS, instead of using the `href` attribute.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan so with that will I be able to use the mouse wheel ?

Comment: This is the default setting of firefox on mousewheel click. It will open a new browser tab on clicking any link. You can attach an event to it. If you want to view the settings use `about:config` in the searchbar and find for middlemouse.

Comment: "use this fiddle example to view it. " — Questions seeking debugging help (“**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve),  [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) and [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Hi, Please have a look on my answer you can use `mousedown` for middle click

Comment: NOTE : The href url should be generated in that function which called by it.

Comment: Hi, I've updated my answer.. doesn't look like firefox allow this to do, you can do using other tags but yes again this is not your question.. however firefox doesn't allow javascript/jQuery events for middle or right click for `<a>` tag

Answer (score -1):

Use onclick to trigger functions, you can also use click event using id or class.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return test()">Test</a>
```

using id

```
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="clickme">Test</a>
```

jQuery

```
$("#clickme").click(function(){
alert("executed");
});
```

For left, right or middle click you can use `mousedown`

- Left - 1
- Middle - 2
- Right - 3

`$(document).mousedown(function(e){ switch(e.which) { case 1: //left Click break; case 2: //middle Click break; case 3: //right Click break; } return true;// to allow the browser to know that we handled it. });`

**EDIT**
I am afraid that right click or middle click on `<a>` tag is against firefox [policy](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=180078), to do so.. you have to change firefox settings.